# Why do Necron immortals have movement 5?

Tags: warhammer-40k, black-crusade

Necron immortals are listed with 5 as base movement and I don't understand why: They have only 35 Agility, with Size 5 (Hulking) which gives them +1, but this only gives them 4. I don't see any other trait improving their movement...

Comment: Seems to be a copy paste error -  cant find the reason either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily answered. Black Crusade is a very poorly edited line of books, replete with errors of every kind. From the ever-entertaining mango-adhesives to the lack of a limit for Mechanicus Assimilation, many mistakes have been made.

By their stats, Necron Immortals should have four base movement, and the five is simply an error.

On the other hand, monsters don't necessarily have to follow the same rules and guidelines as player characters, and GMs aren't under any obligation to use the monsters as written, either. That's not what you asked, though.

Short answer: poor editing.